# Why LAE font encoding isn't needed to write arabic with babel (pdflatex)

Tags: font-encodings, arabic

The manual of [`arabi`](https://ctan.org/pkg/arabi) package mention that you need `LAE` font encoding via `\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}` to write Arabic with babel (pdflatex), 
but with a texlive2019  we can get a correct result without adding `LAE` font encoding !?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}

تجريب كتابة نص

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terminal output for your example is

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arabi/arabic.ldf
Loading the definitions for the LaTeX{} Arabic encoding
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arabi/laeenc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arabi/laeenc.dfu))
Loading the Common definitions for Arabic and Farsi
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/arabi/arabicore.sty
```

From the `(` nesting you can see that the `arabic` option file `arabic.ldf` loads the LAE encoding files `laeenc.def`  and `laeenc.dfu`